# Realm query two object in Android

Tags: android, realm

there is a problem when I use the Realm in Android.

I wrote two RealmObject.

```
public class Feed extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    private String content;
    private long uid;
    ...
}

public class User extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long uid;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

I want to search the result with:
[feed_id, feed_content, user_id, user_name ...]

should I need add a new Object ( FeedUser extends RealmObject) with these fields? Is this waste the memory?

Also I want to listen the change about user Object, if I add the FeedUser, when User changed. How to update FeedUser synchronous ?

thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how [Relationships](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#relationships) work in Realm.

If a user can have multiple Feed objects then you can have `List<Feed>` in your User object instead of defining user id yourself in your Feed. It will be something like this. You can read documentation more to see how you will get User with its feed in one query.

```
public class Feed extends RealmObject { 
    @PrimaryKey 
    private long id;
    private String content;
    ... 
} 

public class User extends RealmObject { 
    @PrimaryKey 
    private long uid;
    private String name;
    private RealmList<Feed> feeds;
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Hi. @Sharj could I find for example all feeds that contains 'foo' in content and also all users who has this feeds? Return user but with only subset of his feeds?

Comment: @dilix I am not aware of such example. You can post your problem as a new question and might get help from the community.